# Digital TV pixelation of picture at Manchester using Winter Hill

Tags: tv-antenna

I believe our closest transmitter is Winter Hill. Lately, our digital TV has been playing with severe pixelation and sound cracking up. Now, our so called "qualified" electrician fitted the socket plate for us. Looks like the type you see on the back of the TV. It's as loose as anything. What should I replace it with?

Also if this doesn't fix it what can I do before we call the engineer? Our LG smart TV is saying the strength of the signal is 80% but the quality is 0% most of the time, but it fluctuates.

I moved the LED TV to the other room which doesn't use a face plate. It's a direct connection from the aerial. This works absolutely fine. It appears this particular engineer knows what he's doing which is good. The signal quality status according to the tv is also MILES better. It has a strength meter built into one of the menus.

I can only assume The issue is with the faceplate. It's the connection on the faceplate that's loose and always has been loose from day one. The faceplate is fixed onto the wall properly. I hear F connectors are better for digital TV.  Would the following be better?
http://www.toolstation.com/shop/Electrical/TV+Satellite/Screened+Socket+Single+Ftype/d190/sd3084/p70967

Comment: The faceplate is loose, or the connection is loose? Have you taken the faceplate off to see if the connection on both sides is good? Tried another cable? Checked any other connections between there and the antenna? Checked the antenna itself for signs of damage? Has anything obvious changed since it last worked? Are there any trees in the way (leaves can block signals; may work in winter but not spring)? With a bit more information on the situation (pictures help a lot) we might be able to help. Complaining about previous people doesn't add anything useful to your question.

Comment: Do you have a pre-amp or any other type of amp? An amp will increase the signal strength but will add a lot of noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital TV, unlike analog, tends to be all-or-nothing. If you've got strong enough signal you get perfect rendering; if you don't you get the kinds of symptoms you've described and the only fix is to get stronger signal (better antenna, possibly an external RF booster amp, switch to a set that has better amps internally, or give up on over-the-air).

Comment: I took the faceplate off just now. I found what looks like the higher quality black cable daisy chained into another regular brown cable. I don't think the brown cable is used so I just trimmed it down. I believe that was the old aerial cable before we called the engineer.  Refitted the cable in place. Now it seems to be ok. Soon find out about any probs since my dad watching footy.

Comment: Just out of curiosity that brown cable that's not used, could it degrade the signal? Couldn't it act as an antenna for noise to be coupled in and thereby degrading the signal so the tuner struggles?

Comment: Digital TV is not all or nothing.   The data goes to box and the box interprets the data to be displayed.  Most dish/cable boxes actually do a decent job of displaying data even with small packet loss.  Now your HDMI connection from box to TV is basically all or nothing - but even a pixelated screen is something.